# Clarifications about Rails and Node.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js

Up to now I've always used PHP with or without a framework but a month ago I decided to start  something new: Ruby and Rails, I found them quite easy and similar to PHP and some PHP frameworks in how they works but using a simpler syntax and many other advantages.

Some days ago I started reading about Node.js, Node.js vs Rails, "why node.js is better"...

I'm a bit confused but my objective is to learn something modern that will not become obsolete in a few months so:

**What are the main differences between Rails/Ruby and Node.js and a framework based on it like Express.js (except that one is written in JS and the other in Ruby)?**

**What are the main advantages/disadvantages of using Node.js and framework based on it instead of a Ruby based solution like Rails?**

Thanks!

Comment: Neither Ruby/Rails nor Node will become obsoolete in a few months. Relax.

Comment: ... ok but what about real time features?

Comment: Could you [edit] to concentrate on one issue?  Possibly remove the third (could be a standalone) and combine the other two?  You are in the range of a good subjective question here, but the scope is too broad.

Comment: edited, for the question about realtime and websockets I'll wait some time!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There aren't enough differences between Node.js and Rails for it to practically matter.

A lot of what Node.js can do can be *pulled off* in Rails with things like EventMachine and Pusher. So unless you are *really* familiar with Rails' limitations, and know you'll be pushing the boundaries, you'd be hard pressed to make something a seasoned Rails developer couldn't do.

Having built apps in Node and Express I can say that they alone aren't enough to make a sexy application. They can seem just as old and stale if you don't have an outstanding frontend UI to facilitate the backend possibilities. Instead of comparing backend servers, I think the real future of doing amazing things is in front-end JavaScript frameworks like [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) that use Express/Rails/Node.js on the backend.

I have chosen to go in the direction of Backbone.js with Rails as my backend API server. Because it's so easy to rapidly create a very nice RESTful backend server in Rails. Rails also makes working with CoffeeScript and precompiling/organizing Backbone code a breeze. There are already decent Backbone.js gems out there for Rails.

The Rails core is also able to acknowledge and embrace the fact that frontend JS MVCs are logically a good next step, and they have been working to strengthen the bond between the two. For those same reasons they have also worked to make Rails an even better API server so that it can work with frontend JS easier. Node.js and Express aren't putting as much effort to coordinate with frontend JavaScript MVCs as the Rails community is.

Being good with a JavaScript frontend MVC and Rails as a backend makes you also great for both worlds in terms of getting a job. You will easily be able to hop onto a Node.js project and add value to that team with your superior frontend experience, and you can also roll with the punches on a Ruby on Rails team and add value to them as well.

Comment: why do you think JS MVC like Backbone.js are the future? what are them advantages?

Comment: Front JS is everything. It allows you to build sexy interfaces quickly that can continuously update small pieces of a web page. It also painlessly queries your Rails API server and grabs exactly the data objects it needs without batting an eye, and it does all of that asynchronously. Building in Node or Express alone just leaves you with a normal website. It'll be asynchronous on the backend, but that doesn't matter if you can't *see* it happening before your eyes.

Comment: The other good thing about front end JS is that you can ship and store your entire application on the client. Your entire application gets loaded on the first request and never needs to query again for additional Javascript or CSS. This also allows you to package it up and ship it out easily on Android and iOS devices.

Comment: Oh and one more thing, you are freed from backend servers. You can build your backend in PHP and if you don't like how it's working you can toss it and use Rails without your application ever knowing or caring. If you don't like how Rails is working, toss it and use Node.js -- in the future if SuperNode comes out, you can toss Node and use SuperNode, or just use HTML5 offline storage -- it all works with your application out of box.

Comment: i can do this without the need of a JS framework... waht are the advantages of using it against making normal AJAX calls and updating the dom with jquery?

Comment: When you want to make an entire application realtime, MVC JS frameworks just give you a lot more muscle to do it. With AJAX calls here and there, you still have to render your own views and write your own AJAX queries, you have to do everything yourself and sort through data yourself. Your JavaScript can easily get mixed around and conflict, and when you're doing it for an *entire* application it gets messy very quickly.

Comment: With JavaScript MVCs all of your JS is organized and your views are organized. You can map the data fields to different parts of your views and say, "Watch these fields" - if those fields ever change the view automatically updates. You get functions to help you query for data and sort through it easily. You don't have to manipulate the DOM, you just map the fields to the DOM and say, "render this view" and it knows what to do. You can also define your own routes, so the whole application never does loads a new page. It makes it really easy to make your whole site a sexy realtime "app".

Comment: wow, a last questiondo you think is better to develop either the app and the site (features, about, signup) using a JS MVC or is better to develop the site normally and the app with a JS MVC?

Comment: I prefer to do as much as I can in the JS MVC, since it can make both a site or an app and it's good practice either way. You also get all of the benefits if you want to add something realtime to the site like, "Total Downloads". If you're just starting you can offload a lot of it to Rails/PHP/Node and simply query for it from the MVC.

Comment: some time been passed since, please check alternatives to backbone and rails: http://derbyjs.com/#why_not_use_rails_and_backbone

Answer (score 5):

As [official Node.js website](http://nodejs.org/) explains it:

> Node.js is a platform built on Chrome's JavaScript runtime for easily building fast, scalable network applications. Node.js uses an event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that makes it lightweight and efficient, perfect for data-intensive real-time applications that run across distributed devices.

On the other hand [Ruby on Rails official website](http://rubyonrails.org/) says:

> Ruby on Rails is an open-source web framework that's optimized for programmer happiness and sustainable productivity. It lets you write beautiful code by favoring convention over configuration.

Given this I guess that it is more appropriate to compare Ruby and Node.js, but even this is not quite right given that Ruby is programming language and Node.js is NOT. You could probably compare JavaScript with Ruby but I guess that is not what you meant to ask with this question :)

So, for me, key point in understanding what Node.js truly tries to accomplish is well described on [Node.js about page](http://nodejs.org/about/). Key Node.js idea (for me) is described in this sentences:

> Node is similar in design to and influenced by systems like Ruby's Event Machine or Python's Twisted. Node takes the event model a bit further—it presents the event loop as a language construct instead of as a library. In other systems there is always a blocking call to start the event-loop. Typically one defines behavior through callbacks at the beginning of a script and at the end starts a server through a blocking call like EventMachine::run(). In Node there is no such start-the-event-loop call. Node simply enters the event loop after executing the input script. Node exits the event loop when there are no more callbacks to perform. This behavior is like browser javascript—the event loop is hidden from the user.

What this should enable you, is that you should be able to easily write highly concurrent programs without even thinking about concurrency using JavaScript syntax and callback functions as basic concurrent runnable units.

Answer (score 4):

Your fear that either Rails or Node.js will be gone in a week is unfounded.  Rails has a large community and will be around for a very long time even though currently (early 2012) it's getting a bit of hate thrown its way.  Node.js is just getting started and has so much attention I don't think it will have any problems getting to the Rails level some day.

That said I've been evaluating Node.js and Rails as options for a project and the reasons I choose Node.js over Rails are:

1. "The Rails Way" - In my (admittedly limited) experience with Rails it really seems like you either do it the Rails way or you are going to be in for a world of pain.  A big part of the Rails way is to use the ActiveRecord model.  The advantage of this is that there are a lot of gems that work with your code happily because they know you'll be using ActiveRecord.  The disadvantage is you are mixing your data access & model.  I am not a fan of this idea so the Rails way for me still seems a bit.. off.
2. JavaScript is a key part of client side web development and the idea of using it on the client and server is interesting.  I'm not super strong at JavaScript and I can't imagine a better way to get better then to have to use it everywhere.
3. My project has real time communication needs which while I'm sure can be done in Rails there seems to be quite a bit of positive mention on Nodes ability to handle this with socket.io being the front runner option.

At the end of the day no matter which you choose you will have a great time & learn a ton of new stuff that will change how you write code.  If you're not on a big time crunch I'd recommend building a small project management tool in both and see which you prefer.

Either way.. Good Luck!

Comment: i'm quite interested in point 3, I think that real time may be a key point of what I'm going to build and I've read that Node.js seems to be the best option for it....

Answer (score 3):

2 things - performance & productivity.

**Performance** (more details [here](http://jslang.info/blog/2014/ruby-on-rails-vs-nodejs))

[image]
<sub>(source: [jslang.info](http://jslang.info/blog/2014/ruby-on-rails-vs-nodejs/ror-vs-node.png))</sub>

**Productivity** (how fast you can build that app)

Ruby on Rails is specialized and highly productive tool for creating so called Web 1.0 and Web 2.0 applications (99% of internet sites are such apps). In my subjective judgement and experience in this area Rails about **2-4 times more productive** than node.js or express.js.

For Web 3.0 apps (realtime things, client-side MVC, etc.) this isn't true, RoR doesn't keep its advantage there.

So **choice depends on use case and priorities**.

Comment: I don't get why Client-side MVC is different between NodeJS & Rails. Both just provides a REST API.

Comment: There's a misunderstanding - I said it's different for Web 1 & 2 sites only. For ClientSideMVC (Web 3) there's no difference.

Comment: The image is obsolete. With a fix made by the original post author they are very close in terms of performance.

Answer (score 2):

I know a lot more about Node.js than I do about Ruby. That being said, Ruby is much more widely adopted. It is currently a very hot skill to have in the work place. Some may argue with me on this but I think that Node.js is still "under development" and will be for a little bit longer. It has a lot of promise but just hasn't been adopted by many companies and projects yet.